# How to monkeypatch an import in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I have the following function:

```py
def _import_some_module():
    try:
        import some_module
    except ImportError:
        print("some_module is not installed")
```

I would like to monkeypatch the `import` keyword in `pytest` so that I can try to raise an `ImportError` even if the module `some_module` exists.
The `some_module` module is a package installed via `pip`.

I tried looking in the doc of `pytest` and `importlib` (monkeypatching the `importlib.import_module()` and `importlib.__import__()` functions) but I did not manage to find anything that worked.

Comment: Related: [How to mock an import](//stackoverflow.com/q/8658043)

Comment: @Aran-Fey The answer you linked to solves my problem. I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same with `pytest`

Comment: Uh, the solution (patching `__import__`) is independent of your testing framework isn't it?